# Антивирус влияет на Android Studio performance - как починить?

Tags: android, android-studio, kaspersky

Выскакивает такое сообщение:

```
Your anti-virus program might be impacting your build performance. Android Studio checked the following directories: C:\Users\Andrew\.AndroidStudio3.5\system D:\Android Development\testDroid C:\Users\Andrew\.gradle C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

По ссылке можно перейти [сюда](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config?utm_source=android-studio#antivirus-impact), но что-то так и не стало понятнее что именно исправить. Я вроде как добавил в антивирусе игнор на студию, но все-равно не особо помогло. Система windows_10 и антивирус KIS (Kaspersky Internet Security). Может кот сталкивался с таким и знает что нужно починить?)

Comment: удалил все антивирусы, performance на все 100

Comment: @iFr0z, ну это уже самый крайний случай))) может есть какие-то еще варианты)) кроме ускорения градла понятное дело)

Comment: ну, я не ради gradle конечно удалил, а вообще для системы в целом :) https://community.kaspersky.com/kaspersky-internet-security-13/your-anti-virus-program-might-have-impact-on-performance-of-android-studio-3367 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202043/windows-defender-might-be-impacting-your-build-performance